# Drawing a Graph in C++ MFC App

Tags: c++, image, mfc, controls, invalidation

I am writing a C++ MFC application to control a machine in a manufacturing setting.  This app also needs to analyze a lot of information in a very short cycle time.

For testing purposes and long term maintenance, I need to be able to graph data coming from a sensor on the console. I may have totally overlooked an option (feel free to propose other options) but my research has taken me to using a picture control.

I am successfully drawing in this control by use of `OnPaint()`. My issue is that I need to redraw a new image every few seconds and I cannot call `OnPaint()` repetitively or pass data to it.

How can I create a new function that can be used to draw on the picture control repetitively? Also, this is my first foray into an MFC app so please explain on an appropriate level. Thanks!

```
class CPicture : public CStatic
{
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
};


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CPicture, CStatic)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CPicture::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
    dc.SelectStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    dc.Rectangle(5, 50, 1000, 51);
}
```

I guess the question is how and where to access this

```
//Picture
class CPicture : public CStatic
{
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    vector<Coordinates> GraphData;
};

void CPicture::OnPaint()
{
    // device context for painting
    CPaintDC dc(this); 

    // save current brush
    CBrush *pOldBrush = (CBrush*)dc.SelectStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);

    int NumPoints = GraphData.size() - 1;

    for (int N = 0; N <= NumPoints; N++) {
        dc.Rectangle(GraphData[N].x, GraphData[N].y, GraphData[N].x, GraphData[N].y);
    }

    // select original brush into device contect
    dc.SelectObject(pOldBrush);
}
```

Comment: You are destroying a [Device Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183553.aspx) while you still have a brush selected into it. This pattern will eventually come back to bite you. Before destroying a DC always make sure to have the original objects selected into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`Invalidate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax04k970.aspx) on your control when new data arrives, or use [`RedrawWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fdz8ey6.aspx) to force an immediate redraw:

```
CPicture myPicture;

myPicture.Invalidate();
```

or

```
myPicture.RedrawWindow();
```

> I cannot call OnPaint() repetitively or pass data to it.

To pass data, a structure containg the data can be declared inside your `CPicture` class (or some place else in your program), and that data can then be accessed from within `OnPaint()`:

```
struct myData {
    int value1;
    int value2; // or an array, or some other data structure
}

class CPicture : public CStatic
{
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:

    myData m_data;
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
};
```

In `OnPaint()` (you should also select the original brush back into the device context to avoid resource leaks):

```
void CPicture::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    // save current brush
    CBrush *pOldBrush = (CBrush*)dc.SelectStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    // check pOldBrush - could be NULL

    // dc.Rectangle(5, 50, 1000, 51);
    // access m_data here, for example
    dc.Rectangle(m_data.value1, m_data.value2, 1000, 51);

    // select original brush into device contect
    dc.SelectObject(pOldBrush);
}
```

---

**Update** (working with threads):

Assuming the following (from the comments):

- for the main thread you have a dialog `CLongbowDlg`.
- for the graph, you have a `PicControl` derived from `CStatic`, and that control is placed on the dialog.
- from the main thread, a worker thread is started to read the data.

> PicControl and CLongbowDlg are defined in the same header, but are
>   independent of each other. I need to be able to call Invalidate() or
>   RedrawWindow() from inside CLongbowDlg's functions because they
>   represent the primary thread.

I'll try to give a short description of one of the possibilities here, because this should actually be a seperate question.

Firstly, an object of `PicControl` has to be a member of `CLongbowDlg`, which I assume is the case (let's call it `m_PicControl`) - So, in class `CLongbowDlg`:

```
PicControl m_PicControl;
```

For the data (I'll be using the above `myData` as example data): in your main thread (the Dialog), create a variable of type `myData`: `m_data` (for larger data you could allocate space on the heap, or use `CArray` or some other container):

```
myData m_data;
```

In `PicControl` create a member variable of type `myData*` and set it to NULL in the PicControl constructor.

```
myData *m_pData;
```

In `OnInitDialog()` (main dialog), provide `m_picControl` with a pointer to the data (or better create a function to do that in PicControl):

```
m_picControl.m_pData = &m_data;
```

When starting the worker thread, also provide it a pointer to `m_data` and/or a pointer to the dialog itself (`this`).

**Make sure to protect the data with a critical section.**

When data comes in, the worker thread can write to it via the provided pointer.

In `PicControl::OnPaint()`, the same data can be accessed through `m_pData`.

To initiate a redraw, there are several ways:

- use a timer inside `PicControl` or in the main dialog, and call `Invalidate()` every time the timer fires.
- to control the redrawing from the worker thread (when a certain amount of new data has arrived for example) a message can be posted, using `PostMessage()`, to the main dialog (using the pointer that was provided when starting the thread - the `this` pointer).

  To receive the message you'll have to create a message handler in the main dialog, and from there call `Invalidate()` on `m_picControl` (you could also post a message directly to PicControl, but I prefer to do it via the main window).

Comment: I understand forcing a redraw.  However, I am not understanding the "when new data arrives" part.  Where do I send new data?  I also need this line to be driven by variables.   dc.Rectangle(5, 50, 1000, 51);

Comment: @bluebass44 - I updated the answer with example code. As for data: _"I need to be able to graph data coming from a sensor on the console"_, so I guess you are receiving the data somehow. Upon receiving, fill in the data structure (`m_data`), and call `Invalidate()`. `OnPaint()` will then have access to the new data.

Comment: Thank you sir.  One more complication.  I am in the process of threading this app because, even a late generation i7 cannot crank the cycle time that I need.  The parts on the production line are moving very fast.  I have a thread for the console that on start spawns a new thread that scans continuously for new data and crunches the data.  The graph information originates in the scanner and needs to be passed back to the console.  Does that change anything?

Comment: @bluebass44 - That would probably be a new question; but when using multiple threads, you can allocate the data on the heap (make sure it is protected - with a `CRITICAL_SECTION` for example), and provide a pointer to that data to your control (when creating it), that way `OnPaint()` can then access that data via the pointer. From the thread that receives the data, you could post a message to your GUI thread, or use a timer inside `CPicture` (or your main window) to call `OnPaint()`.

Comment: @bluebass44 - _"or use a timer inside CPicture (or your main window) to call OnPaint()"_ -> or better, to call Invalidate() or RedrawWindow() instead.

Comment: I am getting an assertion failure on RedrawWindow                               void CLongbowDlg::OnBnClickedSPRScan()
{
 PicControl.RedrawWindow();

Comment: @bluebass44 - Is `PicControl` a member of `CLongbowDlg`? Is there a problem in `OnPaint()` maybe? What if you use `Invalidate()`?

Comment: PicControl and CLongbowDlg are defined in the same header, but are independent of each other.  I need to be able to call Invalidate() or RedrawWindow() from inside CLongbowDlg's functions because they represent the primary thread I was describing earlier and what I thought you were recommending for where to call the redraw.  See above on original post